# Ploting pdf of a continuous function

Tags: python, data-visualization, density-function

I want the plot the value of this list at x-axis and their probabilities at y-axis. I did not find any function in python that does so.

Since my data is continuous, i can't simply divide each number by the length of the list to get probability.

Would someone kindly help me how can i compute the probabilities? I need these probabilities show in a graph.

The  list is :

```
list = [0.183206106870229, 0.27099236641221375, 0.0648854961832061, 0.04198473282442748, 0.37786259541984735, 0.16412213740458015, 0.732824427480916, 0.05343511450381679, 0.2099236641221374, 0.31679389312977096, 0.21374045801526717, 0.14885496183206107, 0.022900763358778626, 0.24427480916030533, 0.3931297709923664, 0.6374045801526718, 0.026717557251908396, 0.2633587786259542, 0.2099236641221374, 0.6145038167938931, 0.4770992366412214, 0.08778625954198473, 0.7137404580152672, 0.22519083969465647, 0.3549618320610687, 0.12595419847328243, 0.46946564885496184, 0.4541984732824427, 0.03816793893129771, 0.030534351145038167, 0.3511450381679389, 0.022900763358778626, 0.5877862595419847, 0.15267175572519084, 0.06870229007633588, 0.48854961832061067, 0.22900763358778625, 0.12213740458015267, 0.6870229007633588, 0.6106870229007634, 0.5152671755725191, 0.5458015267175572, 0.09541984732824428, 0.2480916030534351, 0.2786259541984733, 0.25572519083969464, 0.026717557251908396, 0.18702290076335878, 0.366412213740458, 0.13740458015267176]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to somehow discretize the data to compute its pdf. Otherwise each possible value has an infinitessimal probability (a real interval has infinite values on it). You can do so in Python as follows:

*I name your list parameter vals (try not to use Python keywords for variables)*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.hist(a, density=True)
```

If you want say 20 bins, add `bins=20` in the histogram call. You can also define your own bins (and thus control the discretization - [see documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)). The density option normalizes the histogram so it represents a pdf: Integral over all domain is 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. When i say density=True, it does not produce an density curve because the values on the y-axis get range between 0 and 3.5. So it does not represent probability.

Comment: It does represent a pdf because I said that the integral is 1. You can of course have a value like 3.5 if the width is small enough so the area of that bin still satisfies the pdf constraint.

Comment: You can perform a sanity check by summing up all areas of each bin

Comment: One more question: Is it possible to have range between 0 and 1? Because i will add multiple curves in same plot and if the y-axis values are different then it is problematic.

Comment: If you want each probability to be between 0 and 1, a simple solution would be to compute its empirical distribution after discretizing to the bins. You can compute this as usual: # counts in bin / # total points. One can get counts and bins with numpy as `counts, bins = np.histogram(a, bins=20)` and get probabilities as `counts / len(a)`. If you want to plot this note that `bins` has length 21 because it defines the interval of each bin, i.e. [bin1_start , bin1_end=bin2_start , ... , bin20_end].